# Looping Array of Json to Database Laravel?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I have Json Data like this :

```php
$data = '[
    {
        "OrderId": "1038806370",
        "qtty": "1",
        "Item": "Strawberry 250 gr",
        "SKU": "20091"
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "1038806370",
        "qtty": "2",
        "Item": "Strawberry 130 gr",
        "SKU": "20092"
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "1038806370",
        "qtty": "1",
        "Item": "Strawberry 130 gr",
        "SKU": "20092"
    }
]';
```

and I want to Save in my database MySql using PHP Laravel,...

I Want To save data from json to my table, there are table `Order` values `[orderID,...]` and `OrderDetail` values `[orderID, SKU, Qty]`

This is my code in controller

```php
$order = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($order as $ord) {
    $check = Order::where('orderid', $ord['OrderId'])->get();

    if (count($data) > 0) {
        OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
            'order_id' => $ord['OrderId'],
            'sku_id' => $ord['SKU'],
            'qty' => $ord['qtty']
        ]);
    } else {
        Order::create([
            'orderid'=> $ord['OrderId'],
        ]);
       
        OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
            'order_id' => $ord['OrderId'],
            'sku_id' => $ord['SKU'],
            'qty' => $ord['qtty']
        ]);
    }
}
```

but i dont get what i want, I get `QTY` of `SKU` `20091` is `2` but actual json data is `3`

Comment: Your $data is missing the array brackets: `[{...},{...}]`

Comment: how about save data ? @MaartenVeerman

Comment: You check the count of `$data`, you should check the count of `$check`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're counting the `$data` instead of `$check` variable. You don't really need the `$check` variable either though. I'll rewrite your code below.

```php
$order = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($order as $ord) {
    // use EXIST query to check if Order exists or not.
    if (Order::where('orderid', $ord['OrderId'])->exists())
        OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
            'order_id' => $ord['OrderId'],
            'sku_id' => $ord['SKU'],
            'qty' => $ord['qtty']
        ]);
    } else {
        Order::create([
            'orderid'=> $ord['OrderId'],
        ]);

        OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
            'order_id' => $ord['OrderId'],
            'sku_id' => $ord['SKU'],
            'qty' => $ord['qtty']
        ]);
    }
}
```

But your if/else could also be removed by using the `firstOrCreate()` method.

```
$orders = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    // Get Order Model with orderid = $order['OrderId'] or create it if it doesn't exist
    $model = Order::firstOrCreate([
        'orderid'=> $order['OrderId']
    ]);
    // Get OrderDetail with provided SKU, qtty and orderid or create it if it doesn't exist. 
    OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
        'order_id' => $model->orderid
        'sku_id' => $order['SKU'],
        'qty' => $order['qtty']
    ]);
}
```

You could also do it inline.

```
$orders = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    OrderDetail::firstOrCreate([
        'order_id' => Order::firstOrCreate(['orderid'=> $order['OrderId']])->orderid,
        'sku_id'   => $order['SKU'],
        'qty'      => $order['qtty'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have new issue when used inline code in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231289/duplicate-entry-when-using-firstorcreate-on-laravel can you check it out too ?