# Duplicate Entry when using firstOrCreate on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my Controller

```php
foreach ($dataOrder['items'] as $rowJubelio) {
    DataOrderDetailEcommerce::firstOrCreate([
        'order_id' => DataOrderEcommerce::firstOrCreate([
            'orderid'=> $invoice,
            'cust_name'=> ucwords($cust_name),
            'province'=> $province,
            'city'=> $city,
            'district'=> $area,
            'zipcode'=> $zipcode,
            'phone'=>$phone,
            'fleet_id'=> $fleet,
            'ecommerce_id'=> $ecommerce,
            'date_add'=>date('Y-m-d'),
            'no_resi'=> $no_resi,
            'email'=> $email,
            'order_time'=> $transactionDate
        ])->orderid,
        'sku_id'=> $rowJubelio['item_code'],
        'qty'=> substr($rowJubelio['qty'], 0, -5),
        'price'=> substr($rowJubelio['amount'], 0, -5)/$rowJubelio['qty']
    ]);
}
```

when first that i Called controller everything is good with cerated_at and updated_at same, when i called the controller for 2,3,4 times I get duplicate entry with the same order_id, sku_id and price, but diffrent in created_at and updated_at,...

how to solve that ? when i called for the 2,3 or ect,.. there will not have duplicate entry in order detail ?
[image: Error Duplicate Order Detail]

Comment: Maybe the price has decimals and the database can't find a record when searching so it inserts and truncates them. Try `price => (int) substr($rowJubelio['amount'], 0, -5)/$rowJubelio['qty']`

Answer (score 2):

firstOrCreate has two parameters 1: attributes against which to check 2: values with which the record should be created

```php
firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values);
```

When attributes are provided say like

```php
firstOrCreate(
    //attributes against which check will be made
    //Eloquent will search the database to find a record with id=$idValue & name=$nameValue
    // If a record is found it will be returned
    ['id' => $idValue, 'name' => $nameValue],


    //If a record matching the above attributes is not found
    //A new record with the below values array will be created in database
    ['name' => $nameValue, 'age' => $ageValue]
);
```

In your code above the attributes array is missing from both firstOrCreate so it always creates a new record.